# How to use catch inside an ErrorT in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, error-handling

Let's say that I'd like to rework the following function:

```
runCmd :: FilePath -> ErrorT String IO ()
runCmd cmd = do
  Left e <- liftIO $ tryIOError $ do
    (inp, outp, errp, pid) <- runInteractiveProcess cmd [] Nothing Nothing
    mapM_ (`hSetBuffering` LineBuffering) [inp, outp, errp]
    forever (hGetLine outp >>= putStrLn) -- IO error when process ends
  unless (isEOFError e) $ throwError $ "IO Error: " ++ ioeGetErrorString e
```

It tries to run `cmd` and read the output. If it fails with an IO error, I catch it with `tryIOError`, pass it through to the enclosing `ErrorT` monad, and then deal with the error.

It's kind of a roundabout way to do it, especially since there are functions like `catch` and `handle` that allow me to use a handler to deal with the error. But they are typed `IO`:

```
handle :: Exception e => (e -> IO a) -> IO a -> IO a
catch  :: Exception e => IO a -> (e -> IO a) -> IO a
```

How do I cleanly restructure the above code so that I can handle the IO errors and pass it through the `ErrorT` monad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use `ErrorT`, you can try something like this

```
import Control.Exception
import Control.Monad.Error

wrapException :: IO a -> ErrorT String IO a
wrapException io = do
  either <- liftIO $ tryJust Just io
  case either of
    Left e  -> throwError . show $ (e :: SomeException)
    Right v -> return v
```

But this isn't perfect because you still are limited to `IO` in what can throw exceptions. What you can do to help is to use

```
catchException :: ErrorT String IO a -> ErrorT String IO a
catchException = either throwError return <=< wrapException . runErrorT
```

What this does is grab any exceptions that are propagating up and trap them back in the `ErrorT` monad. This still isn't perfect since you need to explicitly wrap all exception throwing pieces of code in it. But it's not terrible.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid using an `ErrorT` for this in the first place.  Have `runCmd` simply return an `IO ()` (or throw an `IOError` if issues arise), and defer error handling to the callers:

```
runCmd :: FilePath -> IO ()
runCmd cmd =
  handleIOError (\e -> if isEOFError e then return () else ioError e) $ do
    -- same code as before
    (inp, outp, errp, pid) <- runInteractiveProcess cmd [] Nothing Nothing
    mapM_ (`hSetBuffering` LineBuffering) [inp, outp, errp]
    forever (hGetLine outp >>= putStrLn)
  where handleIOError = flip catchIOError

caller :: IO ()
caller = catchIOError (runCmd "/bin/ls") $ \e ->
  -- error handling code
```

If you need to catch the `IOError` in `ErrorT` code elsewhere, you can use `liftIO` there:

```
errorTCaller :: ErrorT String IO ()
errorTCaller = liftIO caller
```